# SVProgressHUD not working

Tags: swift, swift3, cocoapods, svprogresshud

Its not working did everything like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpK5KQdn95w

I get the error that the Module SVProgressHUD is not found

here is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Bachelmatt Garage' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to 
use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SVProgressHUD';
  end
```

Can someone help me please? There where also things for the UITest and ther other Test in there i simply removed them is that causing the Problem?

Comment: "not working" is a little broad. What is your main problem? Adding the pod? what is "the Problem" as you said?

Comment: I get the error that the Module SVProgressHUD is not found

Comment: mostly exiting and restarting Xcode fixes this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to install below code:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 2.1'
end
```

**In your file**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Bachelmatt Garage' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to 
use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
     pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 2.1'
  end
```

**Edited**

**Instead above, Do below code:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘9.0’
use_frameworks!

target ‘YouMe’ do
 pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 2.1'
 end
```

It will help you.

Comment: [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `frameworks' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007faeead60cb8>.

Comment: still there? Really need help or does it not work in tabbed Applications?

Answer (score 0):

This podfile is working for me:

```
use_frameworks!
target 'appName' do
            pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 2.1.2'
            pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
            pod 'FileKit', '~> 4.0.1'
target 'appNameShareExtension' do
        inherit! :search_paths # Because else we get the "conflicting names"
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Podfile write this:

```
pod 'SVProgressHUD', :git => 'https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.git'
```